# Several instances of the same Fragment - Event not working for all instantiated Fragments

Tags: android, events, android-fragments, listener, reusability

I am implementing a messenger with different groups, I created a fragment and its associated layout that I want to reuse for the different groups.

I am using a DrawerList view to select the different fragments.
I created a Fragment array containing the different groups, the first time I instantiate all fragments and add them hidden into the FragmentManager. That's probably not the most elegant, if you have a better idea, do not hesitate.

I can display the different views like I want and populate the appropriate listview.

The FragmentMessengers contains a publish button, my problem is that this event is only working (not triggered) for one of the 2 fragments I instantiated.
I tried to unregister and then register the event through the methods update() / removeListener() but I have the same result.

How can manage these listeners ?

Here are some snippets:

Initialisation of the fragment messenger:

```
private static Fragment[] mFragmentMessengers;
```

Selection:

```
        if (mFragmentMessengers == null){
            mFragmentMessengers = new MessageListFragment[topicKeys.length];
            for (int i=0; i<topicKeys.length;i++){              
                mFragmentMessengers[i] = new MessageListFragment();
                Bundle data = new Bundle();
                data.putString(MessageListFragment.TOPIC_NAME, mTopics[i]);
                mFragmentMessengers[i].setArguments(data);
                FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.content_frame, mFragmentMessengers[i],"MESS_"+i);
                ft.hide(mFragmentMessengers[i]);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
        // Test previousPosition
        Fragment mlf = mFragmentMessengers[previousPos];
        ((MessageListFragment)mlf).removeListener();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(mlf).commit();

        Fragment mlf = mFragmentMessengers[pos];    
        ((MessageListFragment)mlf).update();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(mlf).commit();
```

MessageListFragment:

```
public class MessageListFragment extends ListFragment implements OnEditorActionListener {

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.publishMessage);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG,"onEditorAction "+actionId + " topic_name "+topic_name);
    return true;
}

public void update()
{
    Log.d(TAG,"update "+topic_name);
    try
    {
            EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.publishMessage);

            if (editText != null)
            {
                editText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG,"update Exception");
    }
}

public void removeListener()
{
    Log.d(TAG,"removeListener "+topic_name);
    try
    {
        EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.publishMessage);
        if (editText != null)
            editText.setOnEditorActionListener(null);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG,"update Exception");
    }
}
}
```